# how to change a particular image only once

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have made a game where a car picks up the monster and I count that as a point.So now what I am trying to do is to is to change the color of the car to blue when he picks up one monster and then change back to red after some time.
So currently I

```
isTouching(obj) { // returns true if object is touching box x,y,w,h
    return !(this.x > obj.x + obj.w  || this.y > obj.y + obj.h  || this.x + this.w < obj.x   || this.y + this.h < obj.y );
  },


monsters.array.forEach(monster => {
  if (monster.isTouching(this)) {
    monster.reset();
    monstersCaught += 1;
  }
});
```

do this when a car pickups a passenger.So I tried to draw erase the image of the red one and change it to blue one and again change back to red after 3 seconds.But that did not work.

My working [pen](https://codepen.io/RKR3/project/editor/ANBVpA/) of the game.Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`monstersCaught += 1;` counts up every time, if you console.log(monstersCaught); then you'd probably see 1, 2, 3, etc. I think you want to reset it back to 0 after some time? Plus isnt it cought? Try check if you did the spelling correct and didn't use other variables.

EDIT:

```
monsters.array.forEach(monster => {
    if (monster.isTouching(this)) {
        monster.reset();
        monstersCaught += 1;
        //set car color blue
        window.setTimeout(changecar, 5000);
    }
});

function changecar() {
    //set car color back to red
}
```

Comment: No monstersCaught += 1; is whenever I hit a monster I add the points.No I don't want reset it back to 0 after some time.I want to change the red car to blue car and when it caught the monster and again change the color to red in 5 seconds.For a blue car it it catches the monster then change its color to red and then change back it to blue within 5seconds.I hope i made it clear now.i apologize if my question was misleading

Comment: alright, I will try to look into it, thanks for explaining it

Comment: I made an edit, I didn't figure out how to change the car color, but I am sure you know how to yourself?